# Plotting duration of an action against time in MS Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am trying to create an excel graph with the number of actions that took place in minute intervals. My issue is that these actions have variable durations, some last 1 minute, some last 3 minutes.

Looking at the sample data below, I have 10 actions which take place over 3 minutes. The line graph that I have created only shows the action taking place at its start time. What I want to show is the duration too, as Action 1 took place through the time range so my graph should also take into consideration the time, and count that action in the second and third minute.

I have searched the web and have found nothing on this. Is this even possible with excel, or am i not able to explain what I am trying to do clearly, searching the wrong thing?

Here is the sample data that I am working with:

```
  Action Name   Start Time  Time Taken
  Action 1        00:01:00  00:03:00
  Action 2        00:01:00  00:01:30
  Action 3        00:01:00  00:01:00  
  Action 4        00:02:00  00:03:00 
  Action 5        00:02:00  00:01:30 
  Action 6        00:02:00  00:01:00 
  Action 7        00:02:00  00:03:00 
  Action 8        00:03:00  00:01:30 
  Action 9        00:03:00  00:01:00 
  Action 10       00:03:00  00:04:00
```

Comment: If you want to have a chart with time when your actions ended, simply ad another column and sum up `Start Time` and  `Time Taken`. Then make the chart based on that.

Comment: I need a formula which will be able to calculate the time taken so that it shows 6 transactions took place in the second minute. 2 from the first and 4 from the second minute.